# Controlling Relay Module with Ultrasonic Ranging Module on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, gpio, sensors

I'm trying to use Raspberry Pi Model B+ to create a program that uses an ultrasonic ranging module to control a relay module. I will use this thing I create to detect when a conveyor belt stops moving.

My program will rely on the ultrasonic ranging module to continuously measure the distance. Since there are objects on the conveyor belt, the distance will change continuously as objects move past the ultrasonic ranging module. So if the conveyor belt stops moving, the distance measured by the ultrasonic ranging module will stay the same. When this happens for 5 seconds, my program will turn off the relay module.

My code isn't working right now. What is the problem? Here's what I have so far. (Also note I'm using a GPIO extension board for the ultrasonic ranging module and relay module.)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

TRIG = 11
ECHO = 12
RelayPin = 11    # pin11 

def setup():

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(TRIG, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(ECHO, GPIO.IN)

GPIO.setup(RelayPin, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(RelayPin, GPIO.HIGH)  

def distance():

    GPIO.output(TRIG, 0) 
time.sleep(0.000002)

GPIO.output(TRIG, 1)
time.sleep(0.00001)
GPIO.output(TRIG, 0)


while GPIO.input(ECHO) == 0:
    a = 0
time1 = time.time()
while GPIO.input(ECHO) == 1:
    a = 1
time2 = time.time()

during = time2 - time1
return during * 340 / 2 * 100

def loop():

while True:
    dis = distance()

    print dis, 'cm'
    print ''
    time.sleep(5)
    dis12 = distance() 
    if dis = dis2 
        GPIO.output(RelayPin, GPIO.LOW);    

def destroy():

GPIO.output(RelayPin, GPIO.HIGH)
GPIO.cleanup()                     # Release resource

if __name__ == '__main__':     # Program start from here
setup()
try:
    loop()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:  # When 'Ctrl+C' is pressed, the child program destroy() will be  executed.
    destroy()
```

Comment: Please give a detailed description of the problem and tell us what you have diagnosed so far.

Comment: The ultrasonic ranging module should continuously measure and report the distance between the module itself and the conveyor belt. Since there are objects on the conveyor belt, the distance will change continuously as objects move past the ultrasonic ranging module. So if the conveyor belt stops moving, the distance measured by the ultrasonic ranging module will stay the same. When the measured distance stays the same for more than 5 seconds, my program will shut off the relay module which will then disconnect the power source of the conveyor belt.

Comment: My code is not doing anything right now, and I'm not sure where the problem is. Maybe because there's an error in how I set it up? I've never worked with raspberry pi before, so I don't really know how to debug this.